# How to check if a row exists in Better Sqlite3, and if so, to return. - Discord.js : Better-Sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, better-sqlite3

So the title is actually the main question, but I have two technically. First thing is, I am currently coding a discord bot for the heck of it, as well as I am using Better-Sqlite3 node module. I have the database made, and the command is kinda not working right. The command is !linkplayer (tag). It links the player by storing the tag, discordid, discorduser, and a few others in the database. The command itself is linked with an if/else statement asking if a row on the database exists, and if it does, send a message, and return. If not, then create the account in the database. Only problem is, it skips the sending a message part if it exists, and goes ahead and creates it. I am not sure of how to solve this either.

Opening Code:

```
const sql = new SQLite('./accounts.sqlite');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.once("ready", () => {

    console.log(`Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}.`);

    const table = sql.prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = 'accounts';").get();
    if (!table['count(*)']) {

        sql.prepare("CREATE TABLE accounts (tag TEXT PRIMARY KEY, id INTEGER, username TEXT, user TEXT, clan TEXT, clanTag TEXT);").run();
        sql.prepare("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_accounts_tag ON accounts (tag);").run();
        sql.prepare("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_accounts_id ON accounts (id);").run();
        sql.pragma("synchronous = 1");
        sql.pragma("journal_mode = wal");

    }

    bot.getScore = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user = ? AND clanTag = ?");
    bot.setScore = sql.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO accounts (tag, id, username, user, clan, clanTag) VALUES (@tag, @id, @username, @user, @clan, @clanTag);");

});
```

Command Code:

```
if (cmd === "linkplayer") {

    if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send(`You must include the tag with the #!\nUsage: ${prefix}linkplayer #134613 (Town Hall Level)`);
    if (!args[0].startsWith(`#`)) return message.channel.send('You must include # before the player tag.');
    let playerTag = args[0];

    client
    .playerByTag(playerTag)
    .then(player => {


        let accounts = bot.getScore.get(playerTag, message.author.id);
        if (accounts) {

            if (!accounts.id === message.author.id) {

                return message.channel.send(`The user ${accounts.username} already has linked with this account. If you feel this is incorrect, please DM a staff member for help. Provide proof.`);

            }

        } else if (!accounts) {

            accounts = {

                tag: player.tag,
                id: message.author.id,
                username: message.author.username,
                user: player.name,
                clan: player.clan.name,
                clanTag: player.clan.tag,
            }

        }

        bot.setScore.run(accounts);

    });


}
```

So if someone does

> linkplayer #123456

It will search the Clash of Clans database, and see if that tag exists (Works), then if it does, it should check if the row in the database exists (Seems to be the part that is broken). If the row exists with that tag, then it shoots the message. If not, then it creates the row with that tag.

Currently it just takes the new person who did the command and overwrites the old player info.

**Second Question:**
I actually have been slowly spreading to putting commands into their own file, and exporting them to the main file. However, it seems that when a command involves an emjoi:

```
if (!args[1]) {

            client
            .clanByTag(clanTag)
            .then(clan => {

                let labels = [clan.labels[0].name, clan.labels[1].name, clan.labels[2].name];
                let labelName1 = labels[0].replace(" ", "_");
                let labelName2 = labels[1].replace(" ", "_");
                let labelName3 = labels[2].replace(" ", "_");
                let emoji1 = bot.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === labelName1);
                let emoji2 = bot.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === labelName2);
                let emoji3 = bot.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === labelName3);
                let def = clan.description;
                def = def.replace('https://discord.gg/', '');

                if (!emoji1) emoji1 = "";
                if (!emoji2) emoji2 = "";
                if (!emoji3) emoji3 = "";

                let clanEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                    .setColor(`#312345`)
                    .setAuthor(clan.name)
                    .setTitle(`${emoji1} ${emoji2} ${emoji3}`)
                    .setDescription(def)
                    .addField(`Members:`, clan.members, true)
                    .addField(`Type:`, clan.type, true)
                    .addField(`Level:`, clan.clanLevel, true)
                    .addField(`Required Trophies:`, clan.requiredTrophies + `:trophy:`, true)
                    if (clan.location.name) clanEmbed.addField(`Location:`, clan.location.name, true)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter(clan.tag)

                message.channel.send(clanEmbed);

            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err));

        }
```

If I put that into a separate file (With every bit of it(Just declarations)) then for some reason, it returns null on all the emojis. The bot will find labelName3, and all, but as soon as the emoji comes in, it seems to not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hello, how that part of code must work ? 
`bot.getScore.get(playerTag, message.author.id);`


you declarate it two times in bot on ready. Maybe thats is problem, because `bot.getScore.get(playerTag, message.author.id);` allways will be undefined



`bot.getScore = sql.prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user = ? AND clanTag = ?");`


    `bot.setScore = sql.prepare("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO accounts (tag, id, username, user, clan, clanTag) VALUES (@tag, @id, @username, @user, @clan, @clanTag);");`

Comment: And Sql lite must return promise, so you need use `await` before declarate accounts